# Extract the year-month-day from xts

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, data-munging

I have retrieved an xts via the quantmod package for the S&P500, and specified a certain date range:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SP500", src="FRED")

SP500.noNA <- SP500[-which(is.na(SP500))]

SP500.start <- match(as.Date("2018-12-13"), index(SP500.noNA)) - 30
SP500.end <- match(as.Date("2018-12-27"), index(SP500.noNA))
SP500.period <- SP500.noNA[SP500.start:SP500.end]
```

I want to extract from the xts 'SP500.period' the vector of dates. Much of the documentation for xts is about about how to filter the indices on certain date ranges/sequences, but how do I just retrieve the date information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `index`

```
index(SP500.period)
```

Comment: Will do. Obviously already used index in the code without properly understanding what it was doing -_-'' Apparently can't upvote due to my poor reputation, will mark as answer when able.